# Why was my answer on centering text in Emacs deleted?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question

I've provided a specific and correct answer that works here, but it got deleted:

[How to center text in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11651604/how-to-center-text-in-emacs/11654136#11654136)

What was the problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your answer was flagged as plagiarism, because it essentially implements in code what other answers describe in words. I do however disagree strongly that this is plagiarism territory. I've undeleted it.

Maybe you could edit your answer to explain what it does, include a reference how your code relates to the other answer(s). Giving some explanation instead of *only* posting a bunch of code is generally a good idea, and any impression of plagiarism anyone could get would be mitigated as well.

Comment: I will edit with some explanations.  But how a moderator could agree that the only actual answer provided that's not pseudo-code is plagiarism is a little hard to understand.